# How do I allow only 1 URL in my web app to be accessed via iframe?

Tags: node.js, nginx, iframe, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm running a `NodeJS` App on `NGINX` Web Server. I'm able to access all the URLs in my app via `iframe` on other websites.

Here is my `NGINX` conf:

```
proxy_hide_header X-Frame-Options;
```

How do I restrict the iframe to allow only 1 URL instead of all the URLs?

Also, how do I allow only a few domains to access via `iframe`?

Can it be done via `NGINX` or should it be handled via `NodeJS` code?

Answer (score 4):

It can be done via both NGINX conf and nodejs.
For NGINX conf, please use both X-Frame-Options and Content Security Policy (frame-ancestors)
`add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors domain1 domain2 domain3";` -> it's for modern browsers
`add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM domain1 domain2 domain3";` -> it's for older browsers

To get more details: [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) [Content-Security-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy)

Comment: The code you shared is to restrict the domains accessing my `iframe`. I don't want to restrict the domains, I want to allow only 1 URL in `iframe` for any domain.

Answer (score 4):

It can be done by both nginx or nodejs. If you'd prefer nginx, you should use it within a ***location*** block like:

```
server {
    location / {
        add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'none'";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "DENY";
    }

    location /iframing_is_allowed {
        add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors http: https:";
        proxy_hide_header X-Frame-Options;
    }
}
```

Otherwise, if you'd prefer nodejs, you should set these headers from your JS code in the corresponding endpoints.

If you looking for what options you have, please consult to [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) and [Content-Security-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) docs, as [Thang Duc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4875848/thang-duc) pointed.

Answer (score 0):

I used this in

> Ubuntu 14.04

```
add_header X-Frame-Options "allow-from https://*.sample.com http://*.sample.com";
add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors https://*.sample.com http://*.sample.com";
```

And it worked like a charm.